# wordpress sidebar bootstrap positioning

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, position, sidebar

Basically, what i did- 2 bootstrap spans of 8 and 4. I've put sidebar code into the right one (4 spans), but for some reason, it displays sidebar bellow content, located in span8.

```
<div class="row pull-right" id="pgg">
<div class="span8" id="pagecn">
    <?php the_post(); ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="ttl">
        <?php if ( is_singular() ) {echo '<h1 class="entry-title">';} else {echo '<h2 class="entry-title">';} ?><a title="<?php printf( __('Read %s', 'blankslate'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if ( is_singular() ) {echo '</h1>';} else {echo '</h2>';} ?>
        </div>
<div id="cn">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
     </div>
 </div>
<div class="span4">
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('primary-widget-area') ) : ?>
<div id="primary" class="widget-area">
<ul class="sid">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('primary-widget-area'); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

and css for that piece of code

```
#pgg {
width:948px;
margin-top:4px;
background-color: white;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#cn {margin-top: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens if you accidentally add some padding or margin to the columns, or otherwise alter the default widths of columns, or their parents. Check in the code inspector if that is not happening. Also, seeing your code live would help troubleshooting the issue.

P.S. Do you realize you're using an old and no longer developed version of Bootstrap? Current version is 3.0.2. You could benefit from using it greatly.

Comment: Correct your syntax and it should be working. It seems you didn't close `span-8`

Comment: damn. I did it again. didn't help though.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close a `<div>`, to be more precise the `div.span8` probably that's why it's not right.

```
<div class="row pull-right" id="pgg">
    <div class="span8" id="pagecn">
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <div class="ttl">
                    <?php if ( is_singular() ) {echo '<h1 class="entry-title">';} else {echo '<h2 class="entry-title">';} ?><a title="<?php printf( __('Read %s', 'blankslate'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if ( is_singular() ) {echo '</h1>';} else {echo '</h2>';} ?>
                </div> <!-- /.ttl -->
                <div id="cn">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div> <!-- /#cn -->
            </div> <!-- /.entry-content -->
        </div> <!-- /#post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
    </div> <!-- /.span8 (you forgot this one) -->

    <div class="span4">
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('primary-widget-area') ) : ?>
        <div id="primary" class="widget-area">
            <ul class="sid">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar('primary-widget-area'); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another thing, by default the `.row` class has `width: 940px;` if I was you i wouldn't mess with the default width unless you customized the grid